# Pythagorean theorem for finite inner product space

Tags: abstract-algebra, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $V$ be an inner product space of finite dimension. Let $v_1, v_2, ... , v_m$ be orthogonal vectors in $V$.

How can I show that:

a. $$||v_1+v_2+...+v_m||^2=||v_1||^2+||v_2||^2+...+||v_m||^2$$

b. Let $v_1, v_2, ... , v_m$ be orthonormal vectors in $V$. let $v$ be some vector and $\alpha _i=<v,v_i>$ it's Fourier coefficient. Let $\beta _1, \beta _2, ... , \beta _n$ some scalars. Use the previous result or any other to prove that:
$$||v-\sum \alpha _i v_i||\le ||v-\sum \beta _i v_i||$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You probably missed a squared on the left member of the first equality. To show the first result, try using the fact that $\| x\|^2 = \langle x,x \rangle$ and the bilinearity of the inner product.

Answer (score 0):

For part **a.)**:

We have,
$$
\big\langle (v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_m), (v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_m) \big\rangle = \sum_{i,j \in \{1,\dots,m\}} \langle v_i, v_j\rangle.
$$
Now, since $v_1, \cdots, v_m$ are (pairwise) orthogonal, we have $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$ when $i \neq j$. Thus noting the LHS is just the norm squared of $v_1 + \cdots + v_m$,
$$
||v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_m||^2 = \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle + \cdots \langle v_m,v_m\rangle = ||v_1||^2 + \cdots + ||v_m||^2,
$$
as desired.

Hint for part **b.)**: think of $\alpha_i$ as the projection of $v$ onto its $i$th coordinate.

Comment: Could you help me with b, and detail it more ? 
I see the fact that as a projection, it is the smallest distance from v, so the dist between v and the projections on each v_i is the smallest, but I have problem to show it in a more formal writing.

Comment: See the first 2 theorems in this paper (the proofs are pretty clear and it gives you some nice context): http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH308/leasts.pdf